# Disable bus stop on Google Map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-2

I'm developing an ASP.Net project using Google Maps. My team decided to use Google Maps API v2.

The problem is, I have to replace all bus stop icons on the map with my bus stop icons.  To do this, I have to hide/disable them (or at least public transports) but I don't know how to do this. I searched many times but I have found no solution.

What command can I use to hide these bus stop icons?

*Note:* My team replaced Google Map v2 with Google Map v3.

Comment: Is your team aware that the V2 api will no longer work in about 3months time?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

Answer (score 13):

got it!

```
        var styles = [
    {
        "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
    }
    ];

    map.setOptions({ styles: styles });
```

that google maps control has got a great api !

Comment: Thanks..  helped me...!!

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with Google Maps API v2.  Can be done by using the Google Maps API v3 and styling the map to not display them.  As Duncan_m noted, "[The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)", new development in that API is strongly discouraged.